# How to split a master Word document into multiple Word documents without a section break at the end of the new documents

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I am using Word to create mail-merge documents.
I then use the splitter macro created by Doug Robbins that I will copy below, to create single documents.

The new singles documents have an empty page at the end, possibly due to a section break that is added automatically. When I try to remove that page it changes the full formatting of my document.

How do I fix this? Ideally, how do I change this macro to fix this problem? For example I have a  document that is in Landscape mode. After using this macro the new single documents will have a final empty page in  Portrait mode and if I try to delete this all the document changes in Portrait mode.

Here is the macro I use:

```vb
Sub splitter()

' splitter Macro
' Macro created by Doug Robbins to save each letter created by a mailmerge
' as a separate file.

Dim Letters As Integer, Counter As Integer

Letters = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
u = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.Name
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Counter = 1

While Counter < Letters
  docName = "WRITE NAME OF SOURCE DOCUMENT" & LTrim$(Str$(Counter))
  ActiveDocument.Sections.First.Range.Cut
  Documents.Add
  Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
  ActiveDocument.Sections(2).PageSetup.SectionStart = wdSectionContinuous
  Set oRange = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range
  f = Documents(1).Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.Text
  n = Left(f, 40)

  ActiveWindow.Close
  Counter = Counter + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Ideally If that macro could be changed to give me the wanted result that would be perfect!

Comment: The issue is that all the page formatting information is carried in that section break. Deleting it deletes that information - this is how Word works. I can think of a couple of approaches: 1) determine the Page Setup settings required (from the original) and format the new document with those. 2) Create a new document based on the original main merge document, delete the content and paste into that (use that file name in `Documents.Add`).